# Built in Bluetooth Connection Strength

Tags: bluetooth

I have an Aorus b550 master MB. This MB has Bluetooth connectivity. I am planning to connect my dual sense connector to use it with steam. However, when I do so, there is a big delay between my press and its action in the game and sometimes if I press any button there is no response in the game for this press. These problems are all solved when I connect my controller using the cable. So, Do I need to buy a Bluetooth dongle to increase the Bluetooth connection strength? Note I always sit next to my PC, so I don't know if these problems exist because of the connection strength or not.

Comment: Onboard bluetooth is notoriously bad in most motherboards. Getting an external module is usually the correct move. There is often too much interference on the motherboard with the built in BT module and if it does not have an antenna for the BT, it is almost always not going to function without input delay with a controller or headphones.

Comment: Bluetooth also adds an extra physical and link layer; see https://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-phy-layer . There will always be *some* extra delay, albeit small, and if you're optimizing for gaming, might want to avoid that delay.